# $(X^2-Y^3)$ is prime ideal in $K[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $K$ be a field. I want to show that $(X^2-Y^3)\subset K[X,Y]$ is a prime ideal.

I know that $K[X,Y]$ is factorial, so it is enough to show that $X^2-Y^3$ is irreducible. But Eisenstein does not to work here, does it?

How can I see that $(X^2-Y^3)$ is prime ideal?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The task is to show that $K[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$ is a domain. I thought it is best to show that $(X^2-Y^3)$ is a prime ideal in $K[X,Y]$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: One way is to identify the structure of the quotient ring: it isn't isomorphic to a polynomial ring, but it is to a subring of one.

Comment: So you are saying I should observe $R=K[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$? Because I want to show, that $R$ is an integer-domain by showing, that $(X^2-Y^3)$ is a primeideal.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown may be you can spell that subring and ask him to prove that. I am not able to guess what subring you are talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove that the homomorphism $K[X,Y] \to K[T]$ given by $p(X,Y) \mapsto p(t^3,t^2)$ has kernel $(X^2-Y^3)$.

Then, $K[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$ is isomorphic to a subring of $K[T]$, which is a domain, and so is itself a domain.

Finally, recall that $I$ is a prime ideal of a commutative ring $R$ iff $R/I$ is a domain.

Comment: This looks very interesting. Why does that implify that (X^2-Y^3) is a primeideal?

Comment: @Cornman, see my edited answer.

Comment: the original task is to show, that $R=K[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$ is a domain. So I thought it is best to show, that $(X^2-Y^3)$ is primeideal. Am I mistaken? Your hint is to show that $R$ is a domain "immediatly".

Comment: @Ihf: How can I show, that the kernel of the given homomorphism is $(X^2-Y^3)$. Obviously it is $X^2-Y^3\mapsto t^6-t^6=0$.

Comment: @Cornman, you have to check the conditions on the coefficients to try to solve $p(X,Y)=(X^2-Y^3)q(X,Y)$ given that $p(t^3,t^2)=0$.

Comment: @Ihf, excuse me, but I do not know on how to procced now. I use division with remainder and need to check when the remainder equals 0?